# Showing virtualedit status in lightline

Tags: statusline, plugin-lightline, virtualedit

I've got such mapping in my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <Leader>ve :call <SID>Toggle_ve()<CR>
fun! <SID>Toggle_ve()
    if &ve == ''
        set virtualedit=all
    elseif &virtualedit == 'all'
        set virtualedit=
    endif
endfun
```

and I'd like to a component in the statusline if [`virtualedit`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27virtualedit%27) is not unset.

A bit like what happens in the default configuration for the [`paste`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27paste%27) setting.

So, after I verified from `:help g:lightline` that the default values of

- `g:lightline.active.left[0]`
- `g:lightline.component.paste`

are respectively

- `['mode', 'paste']`
- `'%{&paste?"PASTE":""}'`

my attempt was like this:

```
let g:lightline.active.left[0] += [ 'virtualedit' ]
let g:lightline.component.virtualedit = '%{&virtualedit!=?""?"VIRTUAL":""}'
```

However, the lightline looks like this when `virtualedit` is off:

[image]

i.e., there's a redundant separator.

---

When `virtualedit` is on it looks as expected, though:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A component's separator is shown by default, even if the component is empty. To hide it, include the `g:lightline.component_visible_condition`. From the help:

> A dictionary to store the visible condition of the components.
> Note that this configuration is used to control the visibility
> of the subseparators, not to control the visibility of the
> components themselves. Each expression should correspond to
> the condition on which each component is not empty.
> The default value is:
>
> ```
>   let g:lightline.component_visible_condition = {
>       \ 'modified': '&modified||!&modifiable',
>       \ 'readonly': '&readonly',
>       \ 'paste': '&paste',
>       \ 'spell': '&spell' }
> ```

which explains why, when `&paste` is off, the separator is not shown.

For the case in question, you would need to add

```
    let g:lightline.component_visible_condition = {
        \ 'virtualedit': '&virtualedit!=""'}
```